# Unable to render two datasets from the controller in View

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, chart.js

I am trying to draw a two-line chart with two datasets that share the same labels using chart.js on my ASP.NET MVC app.

I am only getting the data from "Value" plotted on the chart and not "Age" and I cannot find the reason why.

Relevant Controller code:

```cs
public ActionResult GetLineChartData() 
{
    List <LineChartData> dataForLineChart = new List <LineChartData> ();
    dataForLineChart.Add(new LineChartData {
        Date = DateTime.NOW, Value = 100, Age = 20
    });
    return Json(dataForLineChart, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Relevant View code:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "Post",
  url: '@Url.Action("GetLineChartData", "Posts")',
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  data: dataFromForm,
  dataType: "json",
  traditional: true,
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);

    var labels = data.map(function (e) {
      return e.Date;
    });

    var data = data.map(function (e) {
      return e.Value;
    });

    var data2 = data.map(function (e) {
      return e.Age;
    });

    var ctx = scatterChart.getContext('2d');

    var config = {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [{
            label: "Test"
            data: data,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 204, 0.3)'
          },
          {
            label: "Test",
            data: data2,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(242, 204, 143, 1)'
          }
        ]
      }
    };
  }
});
```

(Some code I do not consider important is hidden)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue & Concern**

Because the below line overwrites the original `data` value.

```js
var data = data.map(function (e) {
  return e.Value;
});
```

After the above line, now the `data` array was overwritten as an array of integers instead of an array of objects. Based on your sample response from API, the current value of `data` will be: `[100]`.

```js
var data2 = data.map(function (e) {
  return e.Age;
});
```

From the above line, it can't find the `Age` property in the element. Hence the result of `data2` will be: `[undefined]`.

This is why the `data2` is not rendered in the chart.

---

**Solution**

Create another variable for the data transformation to avoid overwriting the existing `data` value.

```js
var dataset = data.map(function (e) {
  return e.Value;
});

var dataset2 = data.map(function (e) {
  return e.Age;
});

var config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Test',
        data: dataset,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 204, 0.3)',
      },
      {
        label: 'Test',
        data: dataset2,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(242, 204, 143, 1)',
      },
    ],

  },
};
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-pgjidq?file=index.html)